# How to design psychology tests for concept formation?

Tags: methodology, test, categorisation

I've read many papers on concepts, but their tests are sparsely described or abstractly mentioned. I want to test for classic, prototype and exemplar theories. How do you approach the problem?

Some publications I've read:

===========

```
 A Generalization of Hebbian Learning in Perceptual and Conceptual 
 Categorization
 Family resemblance : Internal structure of categaries
 Categorization of Natural Objects
 Reclaiming Concepts
 Categories, Concepts, Fuzzy Sets, and Logical Deduction
 Principals of Categorization
 Basic objects in natural categories
 Concept and conceptual structure
 http://www.foundalis.com/res/poc/PrinciplesOfCognition.htm
 https://www.iep.utm.edu/concepts/#H3
 .... and many more.
```

most of them are from Eleanor Rosch, ..

Reading also the big book on concepts

---

this seem to be informative :

Category norms: An updated and expanded version of the
Battig and Montague (1969) norms
http://www.lcs.pomona.edu/HewlettCognitiveScience/resources/assets/CategoryNorms2004.pdf

Answer (score 2):

There's no one good answer to this unfortunately, the question is too broad. Seems like you have made a decent start, here are two more quite different methods-focused references to add to your reading that might help:

Divjak, Dagmar, and Antti Arppe. "Extracting prototypes from exemplars What can corpus data tell us about concept representation?." (2013): 221-274.

Lee, Michael D., and Wolf Vanpaemel. "Exemplars, prototypes, similarities, and rules in category representation: An example of hierarchical Bayesian analysis." Cognitive Science 32.8 (2008): 1403-1424.